# WSOD , Autoload.php, Composer, and Two /Vendor directories

Tags: 8, acquia-dev-desktop, composer

I'm going to try to be as thorough as possible. I have an AcquiaCloud-hosted Drupal site with 3 environments, dev, staging, and production. My team uses Acquia DevDesktop to work on this site.

The original developers setup the site to move the /vendor directory out of /docroot. I believe they also used a module (Drupal-Composer or Drupal Scaffold, maybe?) that claims to have assembled the site in /web but we do not have that directory in our repo, we have /docroot as per usual. Anyway, the /vendor directory now lives in both the repo root **and** another /vendor directory is in the /docroot directory.

This [problem was raised here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238949/2-vendor-folders-which-is-not-needed) but no one provided any feedback.

I am getting errors such as the following:

[image: OneLogin Saml_Auth class not found]

Similarly, when I attempt to use various functions on the site that depend on a library or some dependency, I receive errors. For example, PHPMailer classes are not being loaded:

[image: phpmailer class not found]

My project directory has a /vendor folder in the root with an autoload.php pointing to the 3-4 autoload files that composer generates:

[image: autoload vendor directory two in project]

and then here: [image: vendor directory in docroot]

I get the dreaded WSOD when attempting to use things like Saml_Auth or form mailers. Otherwise, the site "works" in the sense that I can navigate around in content, load the admin panel, make minor configuration changes, etc. Only when a library or dependency is needed, it seems to break. This leads me to believe that dependencies from repo_root/vendor or /repo_root/docroot/vendor are not being loaded properly.

Misc./errata: Core 8.5.2, Drush 9, Composer, behat, circle ci, phing/ansible builds are no longer being used but their configs persist in the repo. Just ignore those files in the photos.

Does anyone have any idea how I can triage this situation and my dev environments working again?

Thanks a million.

Comment: If you have been orchestrating the site with composer, you should be able to use that file to create a new project from it, and supply the database, and you should be fine. Since you are on Acquia I would strongly advise to use BLT over Drupal Composer project. I don't think this change is as simple as moving the directory out without some other changes as well.

Comment: The autoload.php file should be pointing one level out. For instance, the core one usually looks in the same directory, but you probably want it to look one level back: `return require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: @Kevin Thanks! Just to be clear, I would point the autoload.php in /docroot/vendor to the directory repo_root/vendor/ ?

Comment: It should just be one level up. Which is achieved by using `'/../vendor`, if that is where you moved it to.

Comment: @Kevin I believe this has fixed the issue! Am I wrong to assume that I can safely delete the /docroot/vendor directory from the repo?

Comment: If it is not in use, it does not need to be there. The Autoloader will look where you tell it to look.